# Patch is not updating but deleting my data

Tags: typescript, http, httprequest

I've been trying to use the http requests to update a status of a car, so that it will for example go from 'in progress' to 'canceled'. I am using patch because I do not want to update all data but only statusId.

But what is strange, is that it deletes the car, and I do not get any errors.
Why, as I know patch updates partial data, and shouldn't delete?

```
 const handleCancelTask = async () => {
        try {
            setSubmitting(true);
            const as = await asStorage.getItem();
            const app = await client.tokenClient();
            const updateDto: UpdateStatus = {
                statusId: 989,
            };

            const response = await app!.patch(
                `/car/${id}/status/`,
                updateDto,
            );

            if (response.status === 200) {
                console.log('Updated car status');
            } else {
                console.log('Failed to update cat status');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log({ error });
        }
    };
```

Here's how my button is implemented:

```
 <Button
                        backgroundColor={Colors.red40}
                        source={{
                            uri: uri + '',
                            headers: {
                                'Accept': 'application/json',
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
                            },
                        }}
                            onPress={handleCancelTask}
                    >
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Text text65 white style={{ fontWeight: '700', marginLeft: 10 }}>
                                {t('Cancel Task')}
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </Button>
```

Here's my httppatch in my backend:

```
  [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
    [HttpPatch, Route("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCar([FromRoute] string id, [FromBody] Car dto)
    {
        dto.StartTime = dto.StartTime.AddHours(2);
        dto.EndTime = dto.EndTime.AddHours(2);

        await _authMethods.VerifyHasPermissionForCar(id, Create);
        await _carMethods.UpdateCar(id, dto);
        return NoContent();
    }

    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [HttpPatch, Route("{id}/status")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateStatus([FromRoute] string id, [FromQuery] CarStatusResourceParameters parameters)
    {
        await _authMethods.VerifyHasPermissionForCar(id, Create);
        switch (parameters.Status)
        {
            case CarStatus.Delete:
                await _carMethods.UpdateStatus(id, TaskStatusAsNumeric.DELETED);
                break;
            case CarStatus.Completed:
                await _carMethods.UpdateStatus(id, TaskStatusAsNumeric.COMPLETED);
                break;
            case CarStatus.Canceled:
                await _carMethods.UpdateStatus(id, TaskStatusAsNumeric.CANCELLED);
                break;
            default:
                return BadRequest("Invalid status");
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Any solutions?

Comment: No way to know what's happening on the backend without showing us the backend

Comment: @tobifasc Ops, it is added now.

Comment: What's `parameters.Status` and what happens in `_carMethods.UpdateStatus`?

Comment: Guessing. You send `statusId: 989` and then you check `parameters.Status`. Now if Status is an integer it will have the default which is 0. If `CarStatus.Delete` has value 0,... then you'll always delete the car. The debugger is your friend.

Comment: I have removed the tag 'patch' since this tag is about software patches fixing bugs or security vulnerabilities etc. The OP asks about *HTTP PATCH* method.